# Check multiple fields are disabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-java

I have a website which includes multiple sub-pages. And after filling all the fields in the various sub-pages and you have posted you query all the fields should be disabled.

My question is if there is a way of checking all the elements in a web page are disabled instead of checking each and everyone individually.

Comment: You could try to find disabled elements using XPath and check if number of those match with expected one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ill try and see if that works for me today and i will let you know